# algorithm that determines if a given number n is composite or not on input <n>

Tags: algorithms, turing-machines

Consider the following algorithm that determines if a given number n is composite or not

```
on input <n>
for i = 2..n
check if i divides n
if it does accept
reject
```

a) The loop runs n times so why this algorithm is not polynomial time in the size of input?.

b) How can a nondeterministic TM decide this problem(composite number) in polynomial time? Can we use that nondeterministic TM polynomial time algorithm to solve this problem in polynomial time on a computer. If not why?

Answer (score 0):

1. The size of the input is $\log(n)$ since it requires that much bits to represent $n$ in memory. Hence, the algorithm is exponential with respect to the size of the input.
2. Just ask for the composition. Multiplying can be done in polynomial time.

Comment: Any specific help for the points b?

Comment: As I said, ask for the decomposition of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

n is not polynomial in the size of n. In decimal: 1..9 have size 1. 10..99 have size 2. ... 1,000,000,000 to 9,999,999,999 have size 10. n grows exponential with the size of the input, not polynomial.

A non-deterministic TM can basically guess two factors a and b and then check if a*b = n. That is easily done in polynomial time.

There are well-known and simple probabilistic algorithms that solve the problem in polynomial time in the size of n and there is a quite complicated non-probabilistic algorithm that runs in polynomial time.

Comment: Any specific help for the points b?